# How to delete corrupted file NTFS?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, ntfs

I am trying to delete some files in Arch Linux, but I cannot delete them as they are corrupted, i tried to check my external hard-disk but there is not result. I did the scan with `e2fsck`.

```
e2fsck /dev/sde1
```

Also, I tried to delete with node number:

```
find . -inum 231861 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: e2fsck does not understand NTFS; it is a tool for checking and repairing ext2/3/4 file systems. Also, while telling us what you have tried is good, it would help if you tell us what the actual results were. I'm voting to put this on hold as *unclear what you are asking* for the time being, but suspect that with some additional information this can be an answerable, on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntfsfix

$ ntfsfix /dev/sde1
```